# Global symbol requires explicit package name, when I use a variable from another file

Tags: perl

I am using a hash from another file by **do hash.pl** command.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use feature say;
use strict;

my $givenrepo = "repopo";
my $givenbranch = "master";
do 'hash.pl';

if (exists $REPOS{$givenrepo}) {
say "herewego!";
if ($givenbranch eq $REPOS{$givenrepo}{branch}) {
say "the branch is same too!";
say "IT is $REPOS{$givenrepo}{branch}";
}
}
```

The content of **hash.pl** file:

```
our %REPOS = (
        "aaa" => {
        "branch" => "master",
        "server" => "http://aaa",
        "job" => "aaa",
    },

        "bbb" => {
        "branch" => "master",
        "server" => "http://bbb",
        "job" => "bbb",
    },

        "ccc" => {
        "branch" => "master",
        "server" => "http://ccc",
        "job" => "ccc",
    },
};
```

I get errors:

```
Global symbol "%REPOS" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %REPOS"?) at main.pl line 15.                                                                                                       
Global symbol "%REPOS" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %REPOS"?) at main.pl line 17.                                                                                                       
Global symbol "%REPOS" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %REPOS"?) at main.pl line 19.
```

It works without **use strict**, but I really can't understand, what am I doing wrong? I am taking this variable from another file, but it is declared like **our** there.

Comment: You should also declare `our %REPOS` in main script prior to using it.

Comment: thanks, it works now. Can you explain in an answer, why is to so complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use strict` doesn't allow you to use package variable from external file for the same reason as,

```
use strict;

{
    our $X =1;
}
# our $X;

print $X;
```

Package variables defined in some inner lexical scope are subject to `strict`, so you need to declare it again in order to use it outside of that scope.

However you can declare it prior to lexical scope,

```
use strict;

our $X;
{
    $X =1;
}

print $X;
```

which leaves `strict` without complaints.

If you want to fetch some external config with `do`, then you'll be better with reference

hash.pl =>

```
{
   val => 44,
};
```

main script,

```
my $REPOS = do 'hash.pl';
 .. exists $REPOS->{$givenrepo}
```

Comment: indeed yes, that being said, `use strict; { our $X = 2;} print our $X;` will still work as well. Not the same as with `my` where it is re-declared outside the brackets.